# Guidance for "me too"ers (answerers / commenters and upvoters)

Tags: discussion, new-users, help, meta-faq, traffic

On [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) we have a lot of *short questions* that get lots of views and "a lot" of "me too" or alike answers, comments and upvotes.

Regarding me too upvotes, from [Resistance is Futile's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337846/289691) to [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843/289691)

> Questions often get upvotes because of "me, too" problems. Someone has a problem, finds the answer on existing question and upvotes both even though question might be less than stellar or even rather poor.

Here is one example:

- [After posting I can't see my tweet on timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114225/88163)

This question has been viewed 65k times, has 3 upvotes, has 5 deleted answers (in this case they aren't many, later I might use SEDE to find something more interesting). The protection was applied automacticaly few moments ago due to the deletion of "me too" answers.

Sooner or later these questions become protected so new users and network bonus users aren't allowed to posts answers.

Unfortunately the participation in the local meta is low / slow, so I coming to you, the power users of Stack Exchange, to ask for ideas about might do to around this situation.

I'm thinking in posting a local `faq` specifically pointed to "me too'ers", including brief details about question protection, anonymous votes statistics.

Is there a site that already have done something beyond using the built-in SE system features to tackle a situation like this?

- Have any site created a chatroom for "me too'ers" or alike?
- Have any site implemented a practice of manually adding a "banner" (image) to popular questions to point "me too'ers" to some place internal or external?

Related

- [What is a “protected” or "highly active" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/289691)
- [Kind reminder, voting is Important!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4889/88163)
- [Do we need to have FAQ questions on Meta Web Applications about how Stack Exchange works (not specific to Web Applications)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387208/289691)
- [Making most viewed questions friendlier for non tech savvy users](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4917/88163)

---

This is not a duplicate of [Making a constructive workflow for new users who post "me too" [non-]answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379074/289691) as this other question is [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) specific about "bumping" questions by posting answers. This question besides that also includes the case of people posting "me too" in comments and upvoting as a way to say "me too" is asking for practices implemented in SE sites that go beyond using the built-in features.

While I wrote the original version of this question the Follow feature slipped from my mind. That is another thing that might be included in the `faq` that I mentioned.

---

This doesn't include edge cases like:

1. People posting "me too" answers / comments that **also** are providing **valuable** information not included by the OP.
2. People posting **follow up** questions providing **valuable** information not included by the OP of the referred question.
3. People posting **self answered questions** becuase were not allowed to post an answer to the protected question that might or might not completely answering the referred question

Comment: The people who will read faq on meta are not the people who post me-too answers. Really all you can do is delete stuff as it comes up.

Comment: Thanks @Undo. You are right. I'm wondering if might be good idead to include a banner, even manually on these questions with too links, one to the faq and another to the site main chat room.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Users don't read FAQs (until it's too late and they've already made a mistake). Perhaps an 'answer a question' wizard would work, just like the 'ask a question' wizard?

Answers like that are often flagged as Not An Answer or Very Low Quality, and they end up in the Low Quality Posts review queue, where one of the standard comment options is

> #### This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment
>
> “This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.”

If you ask me, that's enough guidance. If you encounter such a post as a ♦ moderator, just can just open the timeline, find the pending Low Quality Posts review item (regular users only see completed/invalidated ones), choose 'Delete', and selecting this comment. If you're not satisfied with this comment, use [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) to save and apply your own templates.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure a way to have an idea of how effective is the canned comment (perhaps questions having links to questions with views greather than 50k or so)

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387288/289691) regarding the idea of using a custom template, but proposed in specific per-site Metas

## Custom templates

### Meta Travel

[Answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4452/33456) to [Comment templates to be used when flagging for closure / deletion](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/comment-templates-to-be-used-when-flagging-for-closure-deletion/4452#4452)

> Welcome to [travel.se]. This is not a discussion forum; please do not answer a question with another question. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how this site works. If you have a **new question**, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

## Related

- [Please make the canned feedback options in the new first questions/answers queues configurable per site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369052/289691)